# Showing the function $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

Suppose for real numbers $a<b$ one has a function with continuous derivative 
$$f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$$
such that $f(a)=0$ and there exists a real number $C$ with 
$$|f'(x)|\leq C|f(x)|\:\:\:\text{for all}\:\:x\in [a,b].$$

Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b].$

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for any $x\in B_{\delta}(a)$ we have $|f(x)|<\epsilon $, that is $f(x)=0$ in that neighborhood.  Note that $f$ is continuous on a compact set.

If $f$ is nonzero, there exists $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$. Let $w=\inf\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}.$
 Hence for any  $x<w$, we have $f(x)=0. $

Now considering the following, we get $f(w)=0$ which is a contradiction.

$$|\frac{f(w)-f(a)}{w-a}|=|f'(\xi)|\leq C|f(\xi)|, \:\:\text{where}\:\:a<\xi<w.$$

Is my my argument valid? I also didn't use the continuity of the derivative. Thank you!

Comment: How did you deduce that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ implies $f(x)=0$?

Comment: How do you know that $w\neq a$?

Comment: @MathLover Since $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary small number. Suppose for arbitrary $\epsilon$ we have $a<b+\epsilon$, need to show $a<b$. Suppose not, that is $a>b$. Now let $\epsilon =\frac{a-b}{2}$. Hence, we get $a<b+\frac{a-b}{2}<\frac{a+b}{2}<a.$

Comment: The proof seems legit, provided you supply an argument for your first step of the proof. Just want to remark that there is a shorter proof: You can prove that the zero set $$K=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)=0\}$$ is a both closed and open. (Closedness is immediate from the continuity of $f$. To show that $K$ is open, you can show that every point of $K$ is an interior point, whose proof will be more or less the first step of your proof.) Then the only non-empty subset of $[a,b]$ which is both open and closed is $[a,b]$ itself, proving $f\equiv0$ on this interval.

Comment: @SangchulLee i like this argument..this is a topological argument  used in connected sets and indeed [a,b] is connected

Comment: @Parisina I didn't quite get your argument. Try to explain with some example. Say $f(x)=x^3$, $a=0$, and $b=1$.

Comment: Also, the first step is not an obvious observation. To show this, pick $\delta>0$ such that $C\delta < 1$. The you can check that $$f(c)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=0\quad\text{for all }x\in B(c,\delta).$$ Indeed, check that $M=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in B(c,\delta)\}$ satisfies $M\leq C\delta M$ using the mean value theorem.

Comment: @SangchulLee We really don't need the continuty of $f'$?

Comment: Can this be generalized to a Holder-like inequality? E.g., $|f'(x)| \leq C|f(x)|^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1]$ implies $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, we do not need continuity of $f'$. But if it is available, we have wider range of options for proof. (For instance, a proof motivated from Picard iteration is available as you see from the answer below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some concerns about your attempt:

- the $\varepsilon$ is not used in the sequel of the proof.
- It is not clear that $w\gt a$ and it has to be justified.

Here is a sketch of solution (the details have to be filled to not spoil the exercise).
Using the assumption $f(a)=0$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have 
$$\tag{*}    f(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)  \mathrm dt  $$
hence by the triangle inequality and $ \left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert\leqslant C \left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert$, we get
$$\tag{**}   \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert \leqslant C\int_a^x \left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert\mathrm dt\leqslant C(x-a)\sup_{s\in (a,b)} \left\lvert f(s)\right\rvert.$$
Now, going back to $(*)$ we have 
$$\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert \leqslant \int_a^x\left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert\mathrm dt\leqslant C\int_a^x\left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert\mathrm dt       $$
and using (**) with $t$ instead of $x$, we get that 
$$\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\leqslant\frac 12  C^2(x-a)^2\sup_{s\in (a,b)} \left\lvert f(s)\right\rvert.$$
This suggests that for any $n$, there exists $c_n$ such that for any $x\in (a,b)$, $ \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert  \leqslant c_n\left(x-a\right)^n$, where $c_n$ has to be determined.   We will find that $c_n=C^n/n! \sup_{s\in (a,b)} \left\lvert f(s)\right\rvert$ does the job.

Comment: $w$ cannot be $a$. Suppose $w=a$, then $a=\inf\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$, then for any $x> a$, we get $f(x)\neq 0$. However, $f(x)=0$ on $(a, a+\delta)$ for the same delta as above. I'm not sure, if this is good enough to add it.